How to Efficiently Calculate Functions on a 3D Grid Using GPU Parallelization?
I am working on a project where I need to calculate a function at each point in a 3D grid. Initially, I used a nested loop to iterate through all the points and perform the calculations. This approach was multithreaded, dividing the work along the Z axis where each thread handled a portion of the grid:
// Iterate over the Z-axis of the 3D grid
for (int z = 0; z < dim[2]; ++z) {
    // Iterate over the Y-axis of the 3D grid
    for (int y = 0; y < dim[1]; ++y) {
        // Iterate over the X-axis of the 3D grid
        for (int x = 0; x < dim[0]; ++x) {
            // Create a 3D point (pt) to represent the current position in the grid
            vec3 pt;
            // Calculate the X coordinate of the point as a normalized value between 0 and 1
            pt[0] = (static_cast<double>(x) / static_cast<double>(dim[0]));
            // Calculate the Y coordinate of the point as a normalized value between 0 and 1
            pt[1] = (static_cast<double>(y) / static_cast<double>(dim[1]));
            // Calculate the Z coordinate of the point as a normalized value between 0 and 1
            pt[2] = (static_cast<double>(z) / static_cast<double>(dim[2]));
            // Compute the value of the function at the current point
            double val = computeFunction(pt);
            // Store the computed value in the results vector
            results.push_back(val);
        }
    }
}

Now of course the computeFunction() would need to be ported to CUDA but I want to focus on the logic of efficiently dividing the 3D grid of points into blocks of points in parrallel.

I was thinking of this implementation, which returns a 1D array :
__device__ double computeFunction(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x * y * z; // Example function
}

__global__ void compute3dGrid(double* results, int dimX, int dimY, int dimZ) {
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int z = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    
    if (x < dimX && y < dimY && z < dimZ) {
        double pt_x = static_cast<double>(x) / static_cast<double>(dimX);
        double pt_y = static_cast<double>(y) / static_cast<double>(dimY);
        double pt_z = static_cast<double>(z) / static_cast<double>(dimZ);
        
        double val = computeFunction(pt_x, pt_y, pt_z);
        
        int idx = z * dimX * dimY + y * dimX + x;
        results[idx] = val;
    }
}

void launchGridComputation(double* h_results, int dimX, int dimY, int dimZ) {
    double* d_results;
    size_t size = dimX * dimY * dimZ * sizeof(double);
    
    cudaMalloc(&d_results, size);
    
    dim3 blockSize(8, 8, 8);
    dim3 gridSize(
        (dimX + blockSize.x - 1) / blockSize.x,
        (dimY + blockSize.y - 1) / blockSize.y,
        (dimZ + blockSize.z - 1) / blockSize.z
    );
    
    compute3dGrid<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_results, dimX, dimY, dimZ);
    
    cudaMemcpy(h_results, d_results, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    
    cudaFree(d_results);
}

Ultimately, this problem may require trial and error to optimize the block sizes ?
Is there a better way to do this ?
UPDATE:
I would like to answer as much as possible the different questions that have been posted in the comments of the original post :
Here is the code that computes at each point :
double Molecule::getFastNeutralSphericalDensity(QList < Atom* >* list, vec3 point)
{
    if (list == nullptr) return(0.0);
    if (list->isEmpty()) return(0.0);


    Function_Result ret;                                // Multi Data declaration
    ret.Data_1d = 0.0;                                  // Multi data Initialisation
    ret.Data_2d = 0.0;
    ret.Data_3d = 0.0;
    ret = getFastNeutralSphericalDensity_MultiData(list, point);    // Multi data function call
    return(ret.Data_1d);
}

Function_Result Molecule::getFastNeutralSphericalDensity_MultiData(QList < Atom* >* list, vec3 point)
{
    Function_Result ret;                                // Multi Data declaration
    ret.Data_1d = 0.0;                                  // Multi data Initialisation
    ret.Data_2d = 0.0;
    ret.Data_3d = 0.0;

    if (list == nullptr) return(ret);
    if (list->isEmpty()) return(ret);

    double rho, rhototal, imin, imax, valmin, valmax, disttonuclei, dmin, incr;
    Atom *atm = nullptr;
    QList<double> radialdensity;
    int chem;
    int rsize;

    dmin = 5.0;
    incr = 0.05;
    rhototal = 0.0;
    double occmult, mult;

    QList<Atom*>::iterator it;
    for (it = list->begin(); it != list->end(); ++it)
    {
        atm = *it;

        if (atm->isDummy()) continue;

        disttonuclei = arma::norm(point-atm->getCoords());
        //if (disttonuclei > dmin) continue;

        chem = atm->getZDiff();
        mult = atm->getMult();
        if (mult <= 0.001) mult = 1.0;
        occmult = atm->getOccupancy()/mult;
        radialdensity = mol_radial_densities.value(chem);

        if (radialdensity.isEmpty())
        {
            qWarning() << " radial density for atom " << atm->getFullName() << " is missing !";
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            rsize = radialdensity.size();
            disttonuclei = disttonuclei/incr;
            imin = floor(disttonuclei);
            imax = imin+1; // ceil(disttonuclei);
            if (imax >= rsize || imin >= rsize) continue;
            valmin = radialdensity.at(static_cast<int>(imin));
            valmax = radialdensity.at(static_cast<int>(imax));
            rho = interpol_lineaire(valmin, valmax, disttonuclei, imin, imax);
        }
        rhototal += occmult*rho;
    }

    ret.Data_1d = rhototal;                                       // Multi data result
    ret.Data_2d = 0.0;
    ret.Data_3d = 0.0;
    return(ret);
}

The getFastNeutralSphericalDensity function and its helper getFastNeutralSphericalDensity_MultiData calculate the density at a given point by summing up contributions from each atom within a specified range. This type of calculation is often used in computational chemistry and molecular dynamics simulations to model the distribution of electron density or other scalar fields around atoms in a molecule.
For example one of the molecules that we are working with end up creating a 91M points grid, which on multitheraded CPU, takes a few hours to run.
I have successfully made a GPU implementation which runs in about 60 to 80 seconds foor 91M points. BUT I am running into issue regarding memory usage :



Platform
Points Processed
Run Time
Memory Usage (RAM)




CPU
91M
6h
4G (constant)


GPU
91M
70.77s
Up to 16G on a 16G system



What most strange is that I can barely see any GPU usage in task manager as well has the usage of the GPU's memory. RAM usage goes through the roof however at around 16G used when using the GPU method and stays constant at around 7.4G after the computation is done.
UPDATE 2 :
Here is my implementation to the solution (I am still evry new to CUDA)
computeDensityKernel.cuh
#ifndef COMPUTE_DENSITY_KERNEL_CUH
#define COMPUTE_DENSITY_KERNEL_CUH

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "inc/molecule/Molecule.h"

struct CudaAtom {
    float x, y, z;
    float charge;
    float occupancy;
    float mult;
    float* radialDensity;
    int radialDensitySize;
};

__global__ void computeDensityKernel(CudaAtom* atoms, int numAtoms, float* grid, int dimX, int dimY, int dimZ,
    float3 origin, float3 cellSize, float3 sampleSize);

cudaError_t launchComputeDensityKernel(CudaAtom* h_atoms, int numAtoms, Function_Result* h_grid, int dimX, int dimY, int dimZ,
    float3 origin, float3 cellSize, float3 sampleSize);

#endif

and
computeDensityKernel.cu
#include "inc/cuda/computeDensityKernel.cuh"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ float computeAtomDensity(CudaAtom atom, float3 point) {
    float dx = point.x - atom.x;
    float dy = point.y - atom.y;
    float dz = point.z - atom.z;
    float disttonuclei = sqrtf(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
    const float dmin = 5.0f;
    const float incr = 0.05f;
    if (disttonuclei > dmin) return 0.0f;
    disttonuclei /= incr;
    int imin = floorf(disttonuclei);
    int imax = imin + 1;
    if (imax >= atom.radialDensitySize || imin >= atom.radialDensitySize) return 0.0f;
    float valmin = atom.radialDensity[imin];
    float valmax = atom.radialDensity[imax];
    float rho = valmin + (disttonuclei - imin) * (valmax - valmin);
    float occmult = atom.occupancy / atom.mult;
    if (atom.mult <= 0.001f) occmult = atom.occupancy;
    return rho * occmult;
}

__global__ void computeDensityKernel(CudaAtom* atoms, int numAtoms, float* grid, int dimX, int dimY, int dimZ,
    float3 origin, float3 cellSize, float3 sampleSize) {
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int z = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    if (x < dimX && y < dimY && z < dimZ) {
        float3 point;
        point.x = origin.x + x * sampleSize.x * cellSize.x;
        point.y = origin.y + y * sampleSize.y * cellSize.y;
        point.z = origin.z + z * sampleSize.z * cellSize.z;
        float density = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < numAtoms; ++i) {
            density += computeAtomDensity(atoms[i], point);
        }
        grid[z * dimX * dimY + y * dimX + x] = density;
    }
}

cudaError_t launchComputeDensityKernel(CudaAtom* h_atoms, int numAtoms, Function_Result* h_grid, int dimX, int dimY, int dimZ,
    float3 origin, float3 cellSize, float3 sampleSize) {
    CudaAtom* d_atoms;
    float* d_grid;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    cudaStatus = cudaMallocManaged(&d_atoms, numAtoms * sizeof(CudaAtom));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMallocManaged failed for d_atoms: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        return cudaStatus;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMallocManaged(&d_grid, dimX * dimY * dimZ * sizeof(float));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMallocManaged failed for d_grid: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        cudaFree(d_atoms);
        return cudaStatus;
    }

    dim3 blockSize(8, 8, 8);
    dim3 gridSize((dimX + blockSize.x - 1) / blockSize.x,
        (dimY + blockSize.y - 1) / blockSize.y,
        (dimZ + blockSize.z - 1) / blockSize.z);

    printf("Grid dimensions: %d x %d x %d\n", gridSize.x, gridSize.y, gridSize.z);
    printf("Block dimensions: %d x %d x %d\n", blockSize.x, blockSize.y, blockSize.z);

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    cudaEventRecord(start);
    computeDensityKernel <<<gridSize, blockSize>>> (d_atoms, numAtoms, d_grid, dimX, dimY, dimZ, origin, cellSize, sampleSize);
    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "computeDensityKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        cudaFree(d_atoms);
        cudaFree(d_grid);
        return cudaStatus;
    }

    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching computeDensityKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        cudaFree(d_atoms);
        cudaFree(d_grid);
        return cudaStatus;
    }

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float milliseconds = 0;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
    printf("Kernel execution time: %f ms\n", milliseconds);

    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);

    size_t free_byte;
    size_t total_byte;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&free_byte, &total_byte);
    double free_db = (double)free_byte;
    double total_db = (double)total_byte;
    double used_db = total_db - free_db;
    printf("GPU memory usage: used = %f, free = %f MB, total = %f MB\n",
        used_db / 1024.0 / 1024.0, free_db / 1024.0 / 1024.0, total_db / 1024.0 / 1024.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < dimX * dimY * dimZ; ++i) {
        h_grid[i].Data_1d = static_cast<double>(d_grid[i]);
        h_grid[i].Data_2d = 0.0;
        h_grid[i].Data_3d = 0.0;
    }

    cudaFree(d_atoms);
    cudaFree(d_grid);

    return cudaSuccess;
}



Is your function expensive to compute in practice? Does it perform memory operations and what kind? It has a strong impact on where actually bottlenecks are.

If your work is just a parallel map without neighbor access in shared memory/stencil, it is not very probable that multi-dimensional blocks will be of any help. For occupancy you probably want a 1D block size of 256 or 512. You can use the builtin occupancy calculator from Nsight Compute to figure out occupancy on your given hardware. But in the end one always wants to measure performance. So yes, some "trial and error" will be part of it. Just keep in mind that for memory-bound kernels the performance difference between different sensible block sizes like 256 and 512 are probably quite small.

Floating point division is quite expensive compared to addition/multiplication so I would generally rather calculate double x_diff = 1.0 / static_cast<double>(dim[0]) etc. once outside the loop/kernel and inside do double pt_x = static_cast<double>(x) * x_diff. On the GPU I don't necessarily expect to see a performance difference though, as the GPU might be able to use latency hiding (e.g. behind memory transactions from other warps) to avoid noticable compute overheads in memory bandwidth bound kernels.

You say the loops were parallelized using multithreading but seem to be using results.push_back(val); which generally doesn't look like a thread safe operation.

"this problem may require trial and error to optimize the block sizes". There are existing methods to do this tuning, e.g. https://github.com/KernelTuner/kernel_tuner . This kind of tuning really helped for our CFD code, where the optimal block sizes and other tunable parameters differ from kernel to kernel, between different GPUs, between different data types (single/double precision), et cetera.

I think we do not have enough information to really help you further despite the update. For example, the memory usage is dependent of the allocated data but we do not have the real-world GPU code yet (just a simplified code apparently very different from the real-world one based on the CPU version). The same thing applies for speed. Details matters a lot for the two. So far, we can only make (educated) guesses. If you can write a (simplified) minimal reproducible example, then we can guide you to write a faster implementation consuming less memory (if possible).

@Jérôme Richard Ok I will update my post to give as much detail as possible
